# WIFI Working but ethernet is not

Tags: router, ethernet, connection, ipv6, modem

Recently my ethernet connection stopped working. Didn't notice for a while because Wifi continued to work. Basically I keep getting 'unidentified network' doesn't have valid IP configuration.

Tried many different solutions; up to and including resetting windows (10) and uninstalling, reinstalling adapter, driver, reset router & modem. Followed many different solutions online and none worked so far.

Comment: You reinstalled Windows - your second paragraph and the adapter continues not to work. You tried several other fixes as well. The adpater may have a hardware fault. Try a USB Ethernet Adapter and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your provider doesn't provide IPv6 addresses so getting a private IPv6 address is normal.

I'd disconnect from Wifi and attach an ethernet cable. Then I'd proceed to open a windows command line and try:

```
ipconfig /renew
```

That should request a DHCP renew... if you get nothing after that I'd try a new cable and make sure that you're properly wired to your router.

Answer (score 0):

#### Recently my Ethernet connection stopped working.

Your Ethernet connection does not have a Default Gateway set, and the Ethernet IP Address is `169.254.90.229` but the rest of your network is in `192.168.50.*`

`169.254. x.x` is an Automatic Private IP address. An IP in this range means that the computer cannot see the network. A computer using DHCP needs to have an external server tell it what IP address to use.

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated (run as Adminstrator) `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults (reboot required):

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`